# How to Upload images on DropBox from iOS Application

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I am working with an IOS application in which i select photos from my IPhone simulator and i want to upload those pics on DropBox but i am unable to do that. I am not getting the correct parameters in my uploading method.

Here is my code for sending selected pics from my controller. This code will send the images which i selected from my simulator to the the controller in which i write the code for uploading pics to the DropBox:

```
// UIImage *image;
// NSMutableArray *images
// @property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *chosenImages;

for (NSDictionary *dict in info)
{
    image = [dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    [images addObject:image];

    imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    [imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

    imageview.frame = workingFrame;

    self.chosenImages = images;

    RootViewController *rvc=[[RootViewController alloc]init];

    [rvc _startUpload:image];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rvc animated:YES];
}
```

Now in my RootViewController i am writing codes for uploading images in this method:     _startUpload:image method is used for uploading pics

```
-(void)_startUpload:image
{
    NSString *fileName = @"myImage.png";

    NSString *tempDir = NSTemporaryDirectory();

    NSString *imagePath = [tempDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.loadQRCodeImage.image)];

    [imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

    [self.restClient uploadFile:fileName toPath:dropBoxFolder fromPath:imagePath];
}
```

I am not getting my pics in dropbox so please help me that what am i doing wrong and which paths i really used for uploading images. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the dropBoxFolder ?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/ios

Answer (score 0):

There is a iOS SDK, which provide APIs to interact with drop box through your iOS application
Following is the tutorial provided on drop box developer web site.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ios

Following is the operation you need to look at.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files_put

Answer (score 0):

IN .h file :-

```
@interface UploadOptionViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,DBRestClientDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
 DBRestClient *restClient;
 NSString *file;
}
-(IBAction)photoLibrary:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *file;
@property(retain,nonatomic) DBRestClient *restClient;
@end
```

In .m file :-

```
- (DBRestClient *)restClient {
if (!restClient) {
    restClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
    restClient.delegate = self;
}
return restClient;
}

 //-------------Upload file from dropbox --------------------------------------------

 - (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadedFile:(NSString*)destPath
          from:(NSString*)srcPath metadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata {
[presenter hideHud];
NSLog(@"File uploaded successfully to path: %@", metadata.path);
[[[[UIAlertView alloc]
   initWithTitle:@"File Uplaod" message:@"File uploaded successfully"
   delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]
  autorelease]
 show];
 }

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadFileFailedWithError:(NSError*)error {
[presenter hideHud];
NSLog(@"File upload failed with error - %@", error);
[[[[UIAlertView alloc]
   initWithTitle:@"File Upload" message:@"File upload failed"
   delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]
  autorelease]
 show];
 }
```

And called below where appropriate

```
NSString *localPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Info" ofType:@"plist"];
NSString *filename = @"Info.plist";
NSString *destDir = @"/";
[[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir
               withParentRev:nil fromPath:localPath];
```

Here filename is name of file, localpath is where file is sitiuated.
Hope this helps you !!!

Comment: i am not uploading images from the DropBox to my application.I am uploading images to the DropBox from my IPhone Simulator.Please tell me the method for uploading on dropbox??

Comment: thank you for your kind information.when i am try to catch image path and then send to local path ,i am getting error that the array can't give the path.i am not getting the local path for which i selected image .so plz help me for that.